# How to extract user_id from JWT access_token (bshaffer oauth library)

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt

I followed JWT tutorial https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/overview/jwt-access-tokens/

I have created the access_token as follows:

```
$publicKey  = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) .'/Keys/pubkey.pem');
$privateKey = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) .'/Keys/privkey.pem');

// create storage
$storage = new \OAuth2\Storage\Memory([
    'keys' => [
        'public_key'  => $publicKey,
        'private_key' => $privateKey,
    ],
    'client_credentials' => [
        'api' => ['client_secret' => 'secret']
    ],
]);

$server = new \OAuth2\Server($storage, array(
    'use_jwt_access_tokens' => true,
));
$server->addGrantType(new \OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials($storage));

$tokenData = json_decode($server->handleTokenRequest(\OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())->getResponseBody(), true);
```

The response is

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjM1NWM5YjEzNjRkNmUzMmM2YTM0YWQ2NDgzMWM2NzZjZjllYmEyZGIiLCJqdGkiOiIzNTVjOWIxMzY0ZDZlMzJjNmEzNGFkNjQ4MzFjNjc2Y2Y5ZWJhMmRiIiwiaXNzIjoiIiwiYXVkIjoiYXBpIiwic3ViIjpudWxsLCJleHAiOjE1MDk3MjQ5NDYsImlhdCI6MTUwOTcyMTM0NiwidG9rZW5fdHlwZSI6ImJlYXJlciIsInNjb3BlIjpudWxsfQ.QzCb-nFYHaiJQcj8NsiAN8WoPo24MC5xIgNxWCCNO1WCPzJ_iZ7In6YWcdfe3xVcJQRUzECrveYmKFZizVf7P2UYeGiZjd0tUqM972YiF_9ZrIEjVN_L9QSfGCCAQlhCvXFUdWrfMyiLjUi4D4LYELKyPpkDrJ-0QG5ngtBX_-Iy2zH7BaXf_AGAIyJPScdVvhs_4trroWSaJn7I8KRMtihZCV6ucAUVjkiXJ5rL6Pyem--3PRXJX6IoOQtbKUyRxwhUZfHefPHWaHUdwJY3f83gRnJrSfXql0KdF5i1SdUf1VGwEldmdHPnGHCfKKVypjeXzaP9lHqeO63CXVeY2A",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "scope": null,
}
```

Now I can validate the token as follows

```
$publicKey  = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) .'/Keys/pubkey.pem');

// no private key necessary
    $keyStorage = new \OAuth2\Storage\Memory(array('keys' => array(
'public_key'  => $publicKey,
)));

$server = new \OAuth2\Server($keyStorage, array(
    'use_jwt_access_tokens' => true,
));
$validation = $server->verifyResourceRequest(\OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals());

if (!$validation) {
    $server->getResponse()->send();
    die;
}
```

So it validates the token, but I cannot find the way to extract user_id - or "sub" - according to the tutorial payload documentation

```
{
  "id": "394a71988caa6cc30601e43f5b6569d52cd7f6df",
  "jti": "394a71988caa6cc30601e43f5b6569d52cd7f6df",
  "iss": "issuer_id",
  "aud": "client_id",
  "sub": "user_id",
  "exp": 1483711650,
  "iat": 1483708050,
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "scope": "onescope twoscope"
}
```

I wish to get user_id from the valid token (coming through the headers) and use it to collect related user data from my database. How can I do that?

Comment: Please read https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/overview/openid-connect/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I did read it, but I dont understand how it can help me? I wish to store user_id inside the token and then decode it later. OpenID Connect example shows user_id empty at the end and doesn't talk about storing it. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve desired functionality following this guide: https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/grant-types/jwt-bearer/

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you say that you have already reached, with success, the following step :

```
$validation = $server->verifyResourceRequest(\OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals());
if (!$validation) 
{
  $server->getResponse()->send();
  die;
 }
```

which means that a valid access token has been issued, stored somewhere and now it's used by a client then you can easily retrieve the associated user_id like this :

```
  $token = $server->getAccessTokenData( $request->createFromGlobals() );
  print_r( "The associated userid with this token is {$token['user_id']}" );
```

Otherwise, after having succesfully create an access token and you have it you can split it like this :

```
$tokenData = json_decode($server->handleTokenRequest(\OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())->getResponseBody(), true); //here you have the response body as a string and make it a php object
$separator = '.';

list($header, $payload, $signature) = explode($separator, $tokenData->access_token);
//In your case you need only $payload but it's a copy paste from my code testI
$payloadAsString = base64_decode($payload);
$payloadAsObject = json_decode($payloadAsString);
$tokenData->sub = $payloadAsObject->sub ; // Add a new property to your $tokenData object
```

Now in $tokenData you have the sub (user_id). You can do it whatever you like. Json_decode it etc or use it to query your database users' table.

Hope that helped someone..